# jQuery .load() function is hitting my <HttpPost()> action instead of my <HttpGet()>

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an overloaded action in my method, one declared with  and the other with .

I use the Post metod to handle my form's submit button, which works fine.

I wanted the HttpGet method to handle a jQuery .load() action but that is instead also being caught by my Post method.

Any idea what I'm missing?  Do I have to explicitl call a .get() or .ajax() to hit the right action?

Thanks!

-Ben

Comment: *"Do I have to explicitly call a .get() or .ajax() to hit the right action?"* Yes. `load` tries to be "smart," per @Darin's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method could send an HTTP POST AJAX request as stated in the documentation:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

For example

```
$('#result').load("/foo", { id: 123 }, function(result) {

});
```

will send a POST request.

If you want to be sure use `$.get`, or `$.ajax` with `type: 'GET'`. Also don't forget that if you use GET request for AJAX some browsers might cache the results and get you into trouble or at least some weird behavior, so if you want *fresh* contents from your server use `$.ajax` with `cache: false` parameter.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I prefer to avoid doing this manual URL encoding if possible and use the `$.get` or `$.ajax` method. Kind of *feels* more right.

Comment: Me too. Just saying, there's a third way to be "sure." (And **wow** is that an API failure, choosing `GET` or `POST` based on what the type of `data` is? Yikes.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I completely agree with you, it is a weird API. But also we must not forget that it is a well documented API, so we must always read the documentation of the API we are using.

Comment: Indeed. About half my rep is based on having just read a few docs. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, looooooool. Programming is not that hard after all.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will be sure to pay more attention to the documentation in the future :)